# TweenJS Absolute Position (to() method) Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, easeljs

I was told that the .to() method in a tween object moves a graphics object to an exact point on the canvas. However, when I run the code below, the .to() method adds 400 pixels to the circle's original x position, which is 165. So, the circle is going to 565 but I want it to go to 400 pixels on the canvas. Anybody know why this is happening and what I can do to get it to go to 400 pixels on the canvas?

```
<html>
    <title>Pool Game</title>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    function init(){
        stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");
        var circle = new createjs.Shape();
        circle.graphics.beginFill("blue");
        circle.graphics.drawCircle(165, 250, 25);
        stage.addChild(circle);
        stage.update();
        createjs.Tween.get(circle, {loop: false})
                .to({ x: 400}, 1000);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're setting the center point of the circle to 165 via the first parameter of your `drawCircle` call. Check the docs here: http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_drawCircle

You should do something like

```
circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 25);
circle.x = 165;
circle.y = 250;
```